# Cursor in stored procedure of mysql not working

Tags: mysql

I am using following stored procedure and calling a cursor inside it but it is returning me zero data fetched or processed what is wrong in the procedure ?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_ProcessData`(
DummyDate datetime
)
BEGIN
DECLARE MONTH BIGINT;
DECLARE YEAR BIGINT;
declare LBrCode VARCHAR(100);
declare EntryDate datetime;
declare VcrAcctId char(32);
declare DrCr VARCHAR(100);
declare FcyTrnAmt VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE CustName char(50);
DECLARE CreditAmount decimal(18,2);
DECLARE DebitAmount decimal(18,2);
DECLARE BatchCd char(15);
DECLARE SetNo BIGINT;
DECLARE ScrollNo BIGINT;
DECLARE BookType char(10);
DECLARE ActualAcctId varchar(50);
DECLARE ActualBrCode varchar(50);
DECLARE ActualBookType varchar(50);
declare curProcessAMLData cursor

    for

    select distinct * from DummyTable 
    WHERE EntryDate = DummyDate
    AND (ActualBookType = 'XX');
    open curProcessAMLData;
    fetch next from curProcessAMLData into LBrCode,EntryDate,VcrAcctId,DrCr,FcyTrnAmt,BatchCd,SetNo,ScrollNo,BookType,ActualAcctId,ActualBrCode,ActualBookType;
    while fetch_status = 0
    DO  
                SET MONTH = MONTH(DummyDate);
                SET YEAR = MONTH(DummyDate);
                IF(DrCr = 'C')
                THEN
                    SET CreditAmount = FcyTrnAmt;
                    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Master WHERE BranchCode = ActualBrCode AND AccNo = ActualAcctId AND TransMonth = MONTH and TransYear = YEAR)
                    THEN

                        INSERT INTO Master
                        (
                            TransDate,
                            BranchCode,
                            AccNo,
                            Credit,
                            TransMonth,
                            TransYear
                        )
                        SELECT

                                  EntryDate,
                                  ActualBrCode,
                                  ActualAcctId,
                                  CreditAmount,
                                  MONTH,
                                  YEAR
                    END;
                    ELSE
                        UPDATE Master
                            SET Credit = IFNULL(Credit,0) + CreditAmount
                            WHERE BranchCode = ActualBrCode AND AccNo = ActualAcctId 
                            AND MONTH(TransDate) = MONTH 
                                AND YEAR(TransDate) = YEAR;
                    END IF;
                ELSE
                    SET DebitAmount = FcyTrnAmt;
                    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Master WHERE BranchCode = ActualBrCode AND AccNo = ActualAcctId AND TransMonth = MONTH and TransYear = YEAR)
                    THEN

                        INSERT INTO Master
                        (
                            TransDate,
                            BranchCode,
                            AccNo,
                            Debit,
                            TransMonth,
                            TransYear
                        )
                        SELECT

                                  EntryDate,
                                  ActualBrCode,
                                  ActualAcctId,
                                  DebitAmount,
                                  MONTH,
                                  YEAR
                    END;
                    ELSE
                            UPDATE Master
                            SET Debit = IFNULL(Debit,0) + DebitAmount
                            WHERE BranchCode = @ActualBrCode AND AccNo = ActualAcctId 
                            AND MONTH(TransDate) = MONTH 
                                AND YEAR(TransDate) = YEAR;

                END IF;
                END IF;
        SET FcyTrnAmt = 0 ;
    END WHILE;  
fetch next from curProcessAMLData
 into LBrCode,EntryDate,VcrAcctId,DrCr,FcyTrnAmt,BatchCd,SetNo,ScrollNo,BookType,ActualAcctId,ActualBrCode,ActualBookType;
CLOSE curProcessAMLData;
END
```

What changes will i have to make to make it working ?

Comment: A cursor is very hard to debug and going RBAR (row by agonizing row) will make for a very slow query.  My first step would be not to debug but to convert to discrete set-based statements.  This article is written for a sql server audience but the principles still apply and it's very helpful... http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/66097/

Comment: This looks a lot as T-SQL cursor to me. `FETCH NEXT` should be _inside_ the lool (before `END `WHILE`) anyway.